# Golang сортировка строки по алфавиту

Tags: сортировка, golang

Как в Golang отсортировать строку по алфавиту?

Например:
`baacc > aabcc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш пример можно отсортировать стандартной сортировкой массива байт:

```
str := "baacc"
arr := []byte(str )
sort.Slice(arr, func(i, j int) bool { return arr[i] < arr[j] })
fmt.Println(string(arr))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/vG5EPsK1ppL

Answer (score 0):

```
sort.Strings("baacc")
```